# Корректно ли использование бесконечного цикла?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.
Необходимо сделать  бесконечную смену картинок . Мое предположение:

```
while(1) {
  $('#1').toggle();
  $('#2').toggle();
}
```

Смущает while(1): всю жизнь говорили не делать, а тут. 
Корректно ли такое решение? 
Есть ли альтернативные способы реализации?(цикл for не предлагать:))

Comment: Скорее всего, вам нужен [`setInterval`](http://javascript.ru/setinterval)

Comment: Попробуйте setInterval

Comment: @Dmitry, укажите как ответ)

Comment: в чем измерять корректность? приведенное решение в принципе работает

Comment: @Grundy вот только перестает работать все остальное :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а про остальное речи не было :Р

Comment: @Grindy, корректность в данном случае срабатывание внутреннего чувства костыля)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko мой ответ, возможно, поможет решить вашу проблему, но, по моему мнению, он не является достаточным ответом на исходный вопрос. Поэтому я дал его в комментарии. Если вы считаете, что мой комментарий является ответом на ваш вопрос, то предлагаю вам оформить его в виде ответа.

Comment: "Внутреннее чувство костыля" не поддаётся формализации, уточните.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

все остальное перестает работать потому, что вы в синхронном (читай, однопоточном) режиме запускает цикл, в котором скрипт и застревает - поскольку `while(true)` - выполняется всегда, ибо условие `true` всегда истинно.

Мало того, поскольку выполняется он без ограничений по времени (нет sleep, условно говоря) ресурсов ЦПУ он жрет немеряно, все остальные скрипты, даже асинхронные, вполне могут начать притормаживать.

как правильно сказал @Dmitry, используйте [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

пример по ссылке будет работать в асинхронном режиме, вызывая выполнение функции с периодичностью в 3 секунды

Answer (score 3):

[`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) как альтернатива `setInterval()`:

```js
var img = document.getElementById('e-img')
  ,src = [
    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'
    ,'https://graph.facebook.com/10204328181386038/picture?type=large'
  ]
  ,start
  ,current = 0
;

function step(timestamp) {
  var progress;
  if( !start) start = timestamp;
  progress = Math.round((timestamp - start) / 500) % 2;
  if( current != progress) {
    current = progress;
    img.src = src[current];
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);  
}

requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" id="e-img" width="32" height="32" border="0">
```

Бытовым языком, функция вызывается каждый раз, как браузер готов перерисовать экран. Если ничем не загружет – часто. Если призадумался, то пореже. В этой задаче супер частая отрисовка не нужна, и применение `requestAnimationFrame()` здесь имеет только одно преимущество: более точный тайминг, чем `setInterval()`.

Ф-я `step()` вызывается так часто, как браузер готов что-то отрисовать. Мы запоминаем время начала отсчёта, и следим, чтобы прошла хотя бы 1/2 секунды, и тогда меняем картинку.